# PDF::API2 How to return raw PDF

Tags: perl, pdf

I have created a PDF using PDF::API2. How can I return the raw PDF?

Example:

```
my $pdf = PDF::API2->new();

$pdf = PDF::API2->open('./useful_scripts/invoice.pdf');
my $page = $pdf->openpage(1);

my $content = $page->text();
my $font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica-Bold');
$content->fillcolor('black');
$content->font($font, 11);

$content->translate(170, 785);
$content->text($invoice->ott_invoice_number);

#Finally return raw $pdf
```

I am aware of the `$pdf->saveas()` method, but I don't actually want to save my PDF to a file.

Answer (score 1):

`IRC #perl-help` answer:

```
my $raw_pdf = $pdf->stringify();
```

does the job.